# Trouble Animating a Sequence of PNG Images in LaTeX using the animate Package

Tags: pdf, animations, animate, png

Hello LaTeX Community,

I am currently working on a document using the scrbook class and am trying to incorporate an animation of multiple .png images. I have 20 images named sequentially from frame0.png to frame19.png and want to animate these in my LaTeX document.

I've been trying to use the animate package with the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{animate}
\title{animationTest}
\author{Frisbee}
\date{December 2023}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{center}
    \animategraphics[autoplay,loop,width=\textwidth]{10}{frame}{0}{19}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I also tried animateinline with .pdf files but no luck so far.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{animate}

\title{animationTest}
\author{Frisbee}
\date{December 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here is the animation:

\begin{center}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{10}
    \multiframe{20}{i=0+1}{
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{frame\i.pdf}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In both scenarios, one image is being loaded and when I hover my mouse over the image it illuminates yellow like it has some sort of interaction but no animation is shown.

I am working with overleaf and opened the latex pdf file with mac preview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a viewer problem. Try Acrobat Reader instead.